# SQL Server : Tablock, locks before or after select?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

In the following example, when using `with (tablockx)` is the locking done before the select determines the max value, or after? Is there a race condition with insert statements inserting into table "table1", or is it guaranteed that @foo will contain the max value found in the table until the transaction is committed or rolled back?

```
begin Transaction

declare @foo int = (select max(col1) from table1 with (tablockx))
-- Is it possible that max(col1) can be > @foo here?

Commit Transaction
```

If it matters, I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the locking done before the select determines the max value, or
>   after

Before, by the query optimizer before it is executed. It wouldn't help to do it after, after all. This is the locking method for statement you are executing.

> Is there a race condition with insert statements inserting into table
>   "table1"

No, since you are using `TABLOCKX` and not just `TABLOCK`. The latter allows shared locks, but you are getting an exclusive lock on the table via `TABLOCKX`.

> Is it guaranteed that @foo will contain the max value found in the
>   table until the transaction is committed or rolled back

Yup, all other transactions will be blocked (deletes, inserts, updates, etc)

**TESTING**

To test this, create a table an insert a value

```
create table t1_delete (col1 int)
insert into t1_delete
values (1)
go
```

Next, in one SSMS panel run your code but comment out the `COMMIT TRAN`

```
begin Transaction

declare @foo int = (select max(col1) from t1_delete with (tablockx))
-- Is it possible that max(col1) can be > @foo here?
select @foo
--Commit Transaction
```

Now, in a **new SSMS window** try to insert a new value, or whatever

```
insert into t1_delete
values(2)
```

You will notice the query spins. You can see why if you run `exec sp_whoIsActive` from [Adam Mechanic](http://whoisactive.com/) in **another query window**. Specifically, check out the `blocking_session_id` for your insert session. It will be the session with `sql_test` like *begin transaction declare @foo...*.

**Don't forget to commit the transaction after the test**

Answer (score 2):

Tablockx will grab an exclusive lock that is released when the transaction is committed or rolled back. So your comment area would be blocked.

Comment: I knew it grabbed a lock, just wasn't sure if it was before or after it determined which rows the select would return. I figured it logically had to be before the query was executed, but I wanted to make certain.